# How to split strings of different lengths followed by numbers in R?

Tags: r, string, split

This is on request to ask a new question based on a previous one I asked here: I have a list of compounds like the following:

```
Ag0.05Zr1.0
Al0.11W1.0
Al0.18Cr1.0
AlFe
AlFe0.2NiCuCoCr
AlFe0.2NiCuCoCz
AlFeNi
AlFeNiCo
AlFeNiCrCo
AlFeNiCrCoCu0.2
AlFeNiCu0.2CoCr
Cr1.0Mo0.33
U0.33Zr1.0
V0.33W1.0
V1.0W1.0
```

I need to split and place an underscore in between element names. Now the element names can be single Capital letter, or 1 Capital letter followed by a small letter. I have achieved so far placing a '_' in between strings containing 2 letters. However whenever a Single letter element is concerned it is giving the following:

"Element V1.0 in compound Co_1.0_Cu_1.0_Fe_1.0_5_Nb_0.5_6_Ni_1.0 entered does not exist!". (Error message generated by the code) However I want it to be the following:

"V_1.0_Co_1.0_Cu_1.0_Fe_1.05_Nb_0.56_Ni_1.0"

So it is not only grouping single letters with numbers, it is also failing to identify all numbers grouped together. Can anyone please help? I used the following code to achieve this:

```
elem = gsub("(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[0-9A-Z])", "_", elem, perl = TRUE)
```

where elem is my list of compounds.

The numbers are basically element fractions, So the error message should read like:

Error: Element 'Cz' (or 'Z' a single letter element which does not exist in the periodic table), " in compound xyz entered does not exist!

Comment: Please don't add data as image. We cannot copy data from an image. It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Does this suffice? I have updated the post. I need help with finding the solution. Any ideas and help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd try to do this in a couple of `gsub` steps, overwriting `elem` each time. Trying to come up with a single regex might be possible, but at the cost of being complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide multiple replacement patterns in `gsub` using `|`.

```r
# data
elem <- c("Ag0.05Zr1.0", "Al0.11W1.0", "Al0.18Cr1.0", "AlFe", "AlFe0.2NiCuCoCr", 
"AlFe0.2NiCuCoCz", "AlFeNi", "AlFeNiCo", "AlFeNiCrCo", "AlFeNiCrCoCu0.2", 
"AlFeNiCu0.2CoCr", "Cr1.0Mo0.33", "U0.33Zr1.0", "V0.33W1.0", "V1.0W1.0")

# solution
elem <- gsub("(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])", 
    "_", elem, perl = TRUE)

elem
```

```
"Ag_0.05_Zr_1.0"
"Al_0.11_W_1.0"
"Al_0.18_Cr_1.0"
"Al_Fe"
"Al_Fe_0.2_Ni_Cu_Co_Cr"
"Al_Fe_0.2_Ni_Cu_Co_Cz"
"Al_Fe_Ni"
"Al_Fe_Ni_Co"
"Al_Fe_Ni_Cr_Co"
"Al_Fe_Ni_Cr_Co_Cu_0.2"
"Al_Fe_Ni_Cu_0.2_Co_Cr"
"Cr_1.0_Mo_0.33"
"U_0.33_Zr_1.0"
"V_0.33_W_1.0"
"V_1.0_W_1.0"
```

I made two changes to the `gsub` in the original post:

1. I changed the replacement pattern `(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[0-9A-Z])` to two separate replacement patterns `(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])` because the original replacement pattern inserted "_" between double digits as well (e.g., "Cr_1.0_Mo_0.3_3").
2. I added a third replacement pattern `(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])` to insert "_" between capital letters and numbers.

Comment: I think this is the best(/only proper) solution I have received. Thanks @LC-datascientist.